# Why is footer showing only on last page?

Tags: c#, itext, footer

I am trying to make a program that saves an offer in the pdf file. It is working quite ok, but I have a problem with the footer. I followed these [instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573907/Generating-PDF-using-ItextSharp-with-footer-csharp).

Unfortunately the footer is showing only on last page. How can I solve this? I am looking for a simplest solution since I am at my very beginning of my adventure with C#.

Here is my code:

```
public override void OnStartPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
  {
    base.OnStartPage(writer, document);

    PdfPTable tab = new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Testing..."));
    cell.Border = 0;
    tab.TotalWidth = 300F;
    tab.AddCell(cell);
    tab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 300, 30, writer.DirectContent);
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // drukowanie oferty w PDF
{
  if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
    Document oferta = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();

      saveFile.FileName = textBox7.Text.Trim()+".pdf";
      saveFile.Title = "Zapisz ofertę (PDF)";
      saveFile.Filter = "Adobe Reader|*.pdf|Wszystkie pliki|*.*";

      if (saveFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
      {
        try
        {
          PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oferta, new FileStream(saveFile.FileName, FileMode.Create));

          oferta.AddAuthor(label1.Text);
          oferta.AddCreator("Creator");
          oferta.AddTitle(sNrOferty);

          oferta.Open();

          PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;

          iTextSharp.text.Font czcionkaTytul = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, 11.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
          iTextSharp.text.Font czcionkaTabela = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, 11.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK));
          iTextSharp.text.Font czcionkaNaglowek = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, 11.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
          iTextSharp.text.Font czcionkaFirma = new iTextSharp.text.Font(iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, 11.0F, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY));

          // dodawanie logo - działa, nie ruszać :D
          iTextSharp.text.Image logo = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Properties.Resources.Biomedica_Logo_Mailsignature_02, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
          logo.SetAbsolutePosition(420, 750);
          logo.ScalePercent(30);
          cb.AddImage(logo);

          // dodawanie tekstów
          cb.BeginText();

          // some text lines are added here
          //...

          //dodawanie danych klienta
          // imie i nazwisko
          cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);
          cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdanab.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 11.0F);
          cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 700);
          cb.ShowText(textBox1.Text.Trim());

          // pozycja
          cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdana.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 11.0F);

          cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 680);
          cb.ShowText(textBox2.Text.Trim());
          //Organizacja
          cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 660);
          cb.ShowText(textBox3.Text.Trim());
          //adres
          cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 640);
          cb.ShowText(textBox4.Text.Trim());
          //miejscowosc
          cb.SetTextMatrix(300, 620);
          cb.ShowText(textBox5.Text.Trim());

          //nr oferty
          cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Verdanab.ttf", BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 11.0F);
          cb.ShowTextAligned(1, "Oferta cenowa nr: " + textBox7.Text.Trim(), 300, 580, 0);
          cb.EndText();

          PdfPTable tabela = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count); //poniżej - definiowanie tabeli i przenoszenie danych z datagridview

          float[] szerokości = new float[] 
    {
      dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[4].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width,
      dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width
    };
          tabela.WidthPercentage = 95;
          tabela.SetWidths(szerokości);
          tabela.HorizontalAlignment = 1; // 0 - lewo, 1 - środek , 2 - prawo
          tabela.SpacingBefore = 170.0F;
          tabela.SpacingAfter = 12.0F;
          PdfPCell komorka = null;

          foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
          {
            komorka = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(c.HeaderText, czcionkaNaglowek)));
            komorka.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
            komorka.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
            tabela.AddCell(komorka);
          }

          if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
              for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
              {
                komorka = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), czcionkaTabela));
                komorka.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                komorka.VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER;
                tabela.AddCell(komorka);
              }
            }
          }
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("Biomedica Poland Sp. z o.o.", czcionkaFirma));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("ul. Raszyńska 13", czcionkaFirma));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("05-500 Piaseczno", czcionkaFirma));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("tel: +48 (22) 737 59 96", czcionkaFirma));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("fax: +48 (22) 737 59 94", czcionkaFirma));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("www.biomedica.pl", czcionkaFirma));

          oferta.Add(tabela); //dodawanie tabeli 

          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("Oferta ważna do: " + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToLongDateString(), czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("Proponowany termin dostawy: " + textBox6.Text.Trim() + " dni.", czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("Termin płatności: " + textBox8.Text.Trim() + " dni.", czcionkaTabela));

          oferta.Add(new Paragraph(30.0f, "Obowiązujące ceny mogą ulec zmianie w przypadku:", czcionkaNaglowek));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("   * wzrostu kursów walut powyżej o powyżej 5%", czcionkaNaglowek));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("   * zmian stawek cła", czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("   * lub podatków związanych z obrotem towarowym", czcionkaTabela));

          oferta.Add(new Paragraph(30.0f, "Ofertę wystawił/a:", czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph(label1.Text, czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph(label2.Text, czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("Tel: " + label3.Text, czcionkaTabela));
          oferta.Add(new Paragraph("e-mail: " + label4.Text, czcionkaTabela));

          wri.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();
          oferta.Close();

        }
        catch (DocumentException dex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(dex.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
      }
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Brak produktów w ofercie", "Pusta oferta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
  }
}
```

No problems with this code except this footer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book), you shouldn't add a footer in the `OnStartPage` method. Use the `OnEndPage` method as described in the article you refer to. If you want to know why: please read the book.

Also, as explained in the book, you need to set the page event BEFORE opening the document:

```
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oferta, new FileStream(saveFile.FileName, FileMode.Create));
oferta.AddAuthor(label1.Text);
oferta.AddCreator("Creator");
oferta.AddTitle(sNrOferty);
wri.PageEvent = new PDFFooter();
oferta.Open();
```

Page events are triggered every time a new page is created. If you only add the page event right before closing the document, then the event won't be triggered on all pages that were already completed. In other words: the article you've referred to was wrong.

Please use the official documentation when writing iTextSharp code.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much. The problem was in wri.PageEvent after oferta.Open(). The OnStartPage method was a garbage from testing a problem, ther actualy was the same code in OnEndPage. Anyway - thank you :D

Comment: I am not sure if its my fault with this downvote. I pressed up, but I think I am not able to up or downvote since reputation = 13...

Comment: Must have been somebody else. Don't worry about it. I lost 2 reputation, the person who downvoted lost 1. A pity he didn't say why he downvoted the answer as it was correct. I also posted a comment on the page of the original article.

Answer (score 1):

Adding footer in the OnStartPage wont work.

Here is an example :

```
public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            base.OnEndPage(writer, document);

            int pageN = writer.PageNumber;
            String text = "Page " + pageN + " of ";
            float len = bf.GetWidthPoint(text, 8);

            Rectangle pageSize = document.PageSize;

            cb.SetRGBColorFill(100, 100, 100);

            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
            cb.SetTextMatrix(pageSize.GetLeft(40), pageSize.GetBottom(30));
            cb.ShowText(text);
            cb.EndText();

            cb.AddTemplate(template, pageSize.GetLeft(40) + len, pageSize.GetBottom(30));

            cb.BeginText();
            cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);
            cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_RIGHT, 
                "Printed On " + PrintTime.ToString(), 
                pageSize.GetRight(40), 
                pageSize.GetBottom(30), 0);
            cb.EndText();
        }
```

You can check the entire code here.

[CREATING FOOTER AND HEADER](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2008/04/30/Code-sample-for-using-iTextSharp-PDF-library.aspx)

Comment: The answer is incomplete. The main reason why the event only works on the last page, is because the Event is set at the wrong moment. It should be set before opening the document, not before closing it.

Comment: That is right.. Thanks @BrunoLowagie Will keep that in mind. Thx

Answer (score 1):

```
document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("footer string here"), false);
footer.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.HeaderFooter.BOTTOM;
document.Footer = footer;

document.Open();
```

I had to adapt from this code to only display the footer on the last page, before I did the footer was showing up on each page. So I guess to answer the original question posted here it is possible to display a footer on each page.